# What is the best way to override _initProduct() in module-checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.php

Tags: magento2, overrides, preference

What is the best way to override `_initProduct()` function
in:

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.php
```

I have this in my `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
    <plugin name="x_cart_add" type="X\Y\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Method:

```
/**
 * Initialize product instance from request data
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|false
 */
protected function _initProduct()
{
    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    if ($productId) {
        $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the Magento 2 preference to override, for exmple.

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart\Add" />
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart\Add

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart;

class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{

    protected function _initProduct()
    {
      // Do necessary action and return to parent.
    }    
}
```